# ContentResolver insert MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI error

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I want to get a uri by contentResolver insert a music.

```
val contentValues = ContentValues()
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, music.displayName)
contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
```

if not set MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, must be error.

if use same method insert to MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI or MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI is successful.

I'm only want to get a uri for wirte data at Android Q.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(int)' on a null object reference
   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1959)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1603)
```

Comment: most likely you need to fill `AudioColumns` in `ContentValues` - now you leave them empty

Comment: I try to add all columns without DATA then still have the same problem.

Comment: ok, why would you want to call `insert()` at all? cannot you use `MediaScannerConnection`?

Comment: because I prepare to save stream to Music Dir and used to `openFileDescriptor`, but get `FileDescriptor` need a uri, so I want to get uri from `mediaStore`. At Android Q, not save a file by `File()`.

Comment: if you need an `Uri` use `FileProvider` then, but honestly i still dont know why you cannot use `MediaScannerConnection` - it gives you an `Uri` in `OnScanCompletedListener`

Comment: `MediaScannerConnection` only scan local file, my stream from network and none a local path. I want get a uri then save it to local.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For android Q and newer, you should set `MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH` instead of `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "${Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC}")
}
```